# View a 3D-Model in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, model, vuejs3, 3d-model, model-viewer

**I'm looking for a way to embed my 3D-Model** *(.glb, .gltf, fbx. doesn't matter)* **onto my website, which i built in vue 3.** 
However, I am unable to find any package or work around to do so.
 The only npm-package i could find was [vue-3d-model](https://github.com/hujiulong/vue-3d-model), sadly it's still not supporting vue 3, see here: https://github.com/hujiulong/vue-3d-model/issues/287. 
The other thing i stumbled across was [model-viewer](https://modelviewer.dev), which didn't work for me either, i added screenshots of the errors which i got, i used [the code posted here](https://github.com/google/model-viewer/discussions/1835).
[image: errors with model-viewer]

Does anybody know a way how i could fix this? Or maybe an alternative to the two ways above?

 Help would be much appreciated

 Cheers, Josch

Comment: You could look into [TroisJS](https://troisjs.github.io/) or maybe copy the configuration into your project.

Comment: Otherwise, maybe a package in the following list: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#webgl